# PerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using an alert to perform a Segue to another view.

```
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                    performSegueWithIdentifier("proceed", sender: self)

                })
```

I just can't figure out why I get the error:

```
Extra argument 'sender' in call
```

The sender should be just self, right? 
This error is driving me crazy for hours now, I can't figure out what's wrong! 
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try using `nil` as the value for `sender:`.

Comment: I tried using nil, but still get the same error

Comment: Post the full code to know where you have written these lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showAlert() //Calling function
}

func showAlert()
{
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Download Complete", message: "The list of user IDs has been downloaded. Proceed to know who viewed your profile.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
  let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("proceed", sender: self)
  })
 alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
 self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed it :)

Comment: in proceed button click application got crashed? why?

Comment: there might be some segueing issue

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Download Complete"
        alert.message = "he list of user IDs has been downloaded. Proceed to know who viewed your profile."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
        alert.show()

        var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
            performSegueWithIdentifier("proceed", sender: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
```

Comment: Do you mean like this:  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Download Complete", message: "Download complete.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    
    func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
        
        
    
    
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                        
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("proceed", sender: nil)
                        
                    })
    }

Comment: you mean making a func of the whole code or..? I don't see which part of the code you put inside the {}

Comment: you alert view contain any button?

Comment: No that's why I add the UIAlertAction, then it displays a button

Answer (score 0):

So this is my full code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Download Complete", message: "The list of user IDs has been downloaded. Proceed to know who viewed your profile.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Proceed", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                    performSegueWithIdentifier("proceed", sender: nil)

                })


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()






                self.alertController.addAction(self.defaultAction)
                self.presentViewController(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


           }
```

Comment: You cant write any code directly inside class. Put your code for alertcontroller inside a function and call that function wherever you need

Comment: its give error extra arguent sender in call in performSegueWithIdentifier line

Comment: @BramRoelandts I have posted my answer. Please try it

Comment: @BramRoelandts I faced the same problem when I missplaced the code